# Solve the ODE $e^{-y}dx + e^{-x}(-e^{-y}+1)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE $e^{-y}dx + e^{-x}(-e^{-y}+1)dy = 0$. I have tried to show whether it is exact, and it is not:

$M = \frac{\partial (e^{-y})}{\partial y} = -e^{-y}$ and $N = \frac{\partial (e^{-x}(-e^{-y}+1))}{\partial x}=e^{-x-y}-e^{-e}$

So I opted for the integration factor firstly with respect to $x$
$$R = \frac{1}{Q}(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}) = \frac{e^{-x}(-e^{-y}+1)-e^{-y}}{e^{-x}(-e^{-y}+1)}=1-\frac{e^{-y}}{e^{-x}(-e^{-y}+1)}$$

Though I'm not sure how to proceed from here, any guidance please?

Comment: @user2715281 Is there a way in finding that out or is it something you get by practicing?

Comment: @user2715281 What? $e^{xy}$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $e^{x+y}$ @Nightflight but impossible to correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll approach it from another side, multipling $e^xe^y$ both side.

Then equation turns into $e^xdx+(1+e^y)dy=0,\,\,-e^xdx=(1+e^y)dy$.

Then, integrating both side, you get $-e^x+C=y+e^y,\,\,e^x+e^y+y=C$.

Comment: How did you know to multiply by $e^xe^y$?

Comment: That's not the answer. It's just a convenient tool to organize the equation.

Comment: I know but how did you figure it out? Or is it merely by inspection?

Comment: It can be seen through intuition. If you solve several differential equations, it seems to be visible. It is difficult to explain.

Comment: No I understand! I get that a lot in different areas of maths. Just means I gotta keep practicing with ODE's, I've just started but I think that I sorta know now when tackling similar ODE's like this.